# Como usar JRLoader.loadObjectFromfile para generar un reporte

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema con JasperReport agradeceria mucho si pudieran ayudarme a resolverlo, ya que he intentado de todo y no logro encontrar la solución.

Este es mi código donde tengo el botón que me generara el reporte.

```
private void guardarpdfActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


        try {
            ConecBD cc=new ConecBD();
             Connection cn=cc.getConexion();

             JasperReport reporte= null;
            String path= "\\src\\reportes\\reportearticulos.jasper";

             reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);

             JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,null,cn);

              JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer (jprint, false);
              view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
              view.setVisible(true);



 }catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ARTICULOS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }
```

y estas son las librerias que importo:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import loginjavamysql.ConecBD;
import loginjavamysql.Login;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;
```

El error que me marca es en donde dice 
**`reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);`**

Esto es lo que me muestra el error

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method loadObjectFromFile(String)
  location: class JRLoader
```

Answer (score 0):

Cámbialo por:

```
reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(path);
```

Comment: deberias documentar por que hay que cambiarlo, saludos